# Cythonized pyparser not working properly, getting wrong argument count to functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython, pyparsing, cythonize

I have a python project to parse some assembler code

```
asm_parser/
  - asm.py
  - AST.py
  - obj_code.py
  ...
```

Below grammar I have set this parse action class on successful matching (init function gets the tokens)

```
self.dir_map_code_fp = pp.OneOrMore(...).setParseAction(Body)
```

In AST.py the function `Body.__init__()` tokens are receiving

```
class Body(Node):
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        super(Body,self).__init__()
        self.code = tokens
```

Then I call `parseString()` on the grammar using the input file string

```
self.parser_asm.parseString(string, parseAll=True)
```

To hide the source I am converting these python files to .so files using cythonize. Below is the **setup.py** file that I am using to create .so files

```
class MyBuildExt(build_ext):
    def run(self):
        build_ext.run(self)
        build_dir = Path(self.build_lib)
        root_dir = Path(__file__).parent
        target_dir = build_dir if not self.inplace else root_dir
        self.copy_file(Path('assembler') / '__init__.py', root_dir, target_dir)
        self.copy_file(Path('assembler') / '__main__.py', root_dir, target_dir)

    def copy_file(self, path, source_dir, destination_dir):
        if not (source_dir / path).exists():
            return
        shutil.copyfile(str(source_dir / path), str(destination_dir / path))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ext_modules = [
        Extension(...) for f in files
    ]

    setup(
        name="myasm",
        ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules, nthreads=8),
        cmdclass=dict(build_ext=MyBuildExt),
        packages=["asm"]
    )
```

After creating the so files I created a run_asm.py file to run the asm code as a wrapper. I import all the so file modules to this run_asm.py

```
import argparse
from asm import Preprocessor

if __name__ == "__main__":
    argParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Assembler')
    argParser.add_argument('-asm', '--asm', required=True, help="Assembly file")
    argParser.add_argument('-outdir', '--outdir', required=False, default='.', help="default_img directory")
    args = argParser.parse_args()
    prep = Preprocessor()
```

In pure python form project is working. In cythonized .so form Argparsing, file reading all things are working until `parseAction()` call to the `Body.__init__()` function. init function only takes two and here it is given four

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_asm.py", line 30, in <module>
    prep.generate_ast(f, args.outdir)
  File "pkg/asm.py", line 145, in pkg.assembler.Preprocessor.generate_ast
  File "/u/nalaka/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1206, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "/u/nalaka/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1072, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/u/nalaka/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 2923, in parseImpl
    loc, tokens = self_expr_parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
  File "/u/nalaka/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1072, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/u/nalaka/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 2607, in parseImpl
    return e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "/u/nalaka/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1098, in _parseNoCache
    tokens = fn( instring, tokensStart, retTokens )
  File "/u/nalaka/intelpython2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 819, in wrapper
    ret = func(*args[limit[0]:])
  File "pkg/AST.py", line 28, in pkg.AST.Body.__init__
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (4 given)
```

I looked at pyparsing.py code, below `func` is the `Body.__init__()` function. In pure python version `limit[0] = 2` but cythonized version `limit[0] = 0` so the argument count is changed in the two versions. I couldn't get more information on this.

```
def wrapper(*args):
    while 1:
        try:
            ret = func(*args[limit[0]:])
            foundArity[0] = True
            return ret
```

Also I found `parseAction()` is callable method with 0-3 arguments `C{fn(s,loc,toks)}, C{fn(loc,toks)}, C{fn(toks)}, or just C{fn()}`. I wonder is this have anything do with this (somehow messing up the argument counts)
Can any one help me to resolve this. I am using intelpython 2.7, pyparsing-2.4.7 and Cython '0.25.2'

Comment: Cython 0.25 is about 4 years out of date by now. Why not try with a recent version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with `Cython '0.29.17'` got the same error. This workaround will help if you are stuck with python2.
Even if I define the function as `def __init__(self, s, loc, tokens):` error is still appearing because for the different token sequences matching the same grammar will call the registered function in `parseAction()` with different number of arguments.
I modified the function to accept variable number of arguments because of this dynamic behavior. When the arg count is 2 (self included) the second is the tokens, when count is 4 it is the last. So getting the last of the arg would be enough.

```
class Body(Node):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Body,self).__init__()
        tokens = args[-1]
        self.code = tokens
```

Comment: Great workaround! Will add this to the pyparsing documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with cythonize, will definitely look into it.

Pyparsing's internal code that handles the various method signatures has a check for raised TypeErrors, to detect whether the TypeError comes from its own signature testing (which is internally created and so is caught and handled) or from within the body of the parse action (which would be a TypeError created by user-provided code, and so must be re-raised). It seems that this TypeError internal-vs-user-supplied detection logic is not working correctly with cythonized code.

Can you try changing the `Body.__init__` signature from `def __init__(self, tokens):` to `def __init__(self, s, loc, tokens):`? This will continue to work in both python and cython versions.

And if there is any way you can move to Python3, I strongly encourage you to do so.

Comment: I think a lot of introspection is difficult to do in Cython so based on your description it's plausible that this wouldn't work. That said, it has improved in the last 4 years so the hugely outdated version that OP is using may not be helping

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  with Cython '0.29.17' also I got the same error. But based on your answer I found a workaround